# When was the thickness of the Earth's crust calculated?

Tags: geology, sedimentology, crust, geologic-layers

When was the average thickness of the Earth's crust first calculated or estimated? What did scientists know about the thickness of the Earth's crust before the 20th century? In what interval(s) fell their measurements?

Comment: the earths lithosphere was discovered in the early 20th century so you second question is meaningless.